# Changing theme layout to RTL

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, theme, design

I have magento theme with a two store views english and arabic
the default theme is working great for the english view but for arabic view i want to change all the layout to be RTL

What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: If you are using custom theme please confirm if RTL is supported  with the theme. If not then you have to either get it done from someone or theme developer.